# Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy' when I try to run a groovy spock tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, groovy, spock

I am getting an error when trying to run a groovy test with MockMvc

My test class looks like below:

```
@WebMvcTest
class BehavioralTest extends Specification{

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mvc;

// my test cases here
```

stack trace here:

```
    Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:333)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:320)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:313)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:299)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:143)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:227)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:218)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:140)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor.process(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:72)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.executeWithServices(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:144)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor$ExecuteTasks.call(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:54)
    at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor$ExecuteTasks.call(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.execute(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$executeTasks$7(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:238)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$tryTransition$8(StateTransitionController.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.tryTransition(StateTransitionController.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.executeTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkGraphController$DefaultBuildWorkGraph.runWork(DefaultBuildWorkGraphController.java:142)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.doBuild(DefaultBuildController.java:231)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:270)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:119)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:124)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.doRun(DefaultBuildController.java:204)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.access$000(DefaultBuildController.java:51)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController$BuildOpRunnable.run(DefaultBuildController.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpecialMethodCall.checkIsConditionBlock(SpecialMethodCall.java:269)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpecialMethodCall.parse(SpecialMethodCall.java:172)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.visitMethodCallExpression(AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:123)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.doVisitMethodCallExpression(AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:170)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.DeepBlockRewriter.doVisitMethodCallExpression(DeepBlockRewriter.java:148)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.visitMethodCallExpression(AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:132)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.doVisitMethodCallExpression(AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:170)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.DeepBlockRewriter.doVisitMethodCallExpression(DeepBlockRewriter.java:148)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.visitMethodCallExpression(AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:132)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.doVisitExpressionStatement(AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:162)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.DeepBlockRewriter.visitInteractionAwareExpressionStatement(DeepBlockRewriter.java:96)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.DeepBlockRewriter.doVisitExpressionStatement(DeepBlockRewriter.java:78)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.visitExpressionStatement(AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:100)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.StatementReplacingVisitorSupport.replace(StatementReplacingVisitorSupport.java:44)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.visit(AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:84)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.DeepBlockRewriter.visit(DeepBlockRewriter.java:56)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpecRewriter.visitAnyBlock(SpecRewriter.java:405)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.model.WhenBlock.accept(WhenBlock.java:32)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.model.Method.accept(Method.java:70)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.model.Spec.accept(Spec.java:112)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform$Impl.processSpec(SpockTransform.java:76)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform$Impl.visit(SpockTransform.java:63)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform.visit(SpockTransform.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:270)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.GroovyCompilerFactory$DaemonSideCompiler.execute(GroovyCompilerFactory.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.GroovyCompilerFactory$DaemonSideCompiler.execute(GroovyCompilerFactory.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerWorkAction.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:135)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:49)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker.executeInClassLoader(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.IsolatedClassloaderWorker.run(IsolatedClassloaderWorker.java:49)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.IsolatedClassloaderWorker.run(IsolatedClassloaderWorker.java:30)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.run(WorkerDaemonServer.java:87)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.run(WorkerDaemonServer.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction$1.call(WorkerAction.java:138)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.WorkerLogEventListener.withWorkerLoggingProtocol(WorkerLogEventListener.java:41)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:135)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
```

When adding compileTestGroovy.enabled = false in build.gradle as was proposed in another answer now I am getting this:

Execution failed for task ':test'.

```
No tests found for given includes: [com.example.MyTestClass](--tests filter)
```

Interestingly it also breaks all the other groovy tests in my application (not only on the annotated class).

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example otherwise we can't really help you. Otherwise, use https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/ as a starting point. Also, you should always post the full stacktrace not just the message, or even more helpful a Build Scan https://scans.gradle.com/

Comment: I've added stack trace and the class. There is really nothing to show, it is taken from Spock examples posted on StackOverflow all over the place.

Comment: The problem is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`, Is this a spring boot project?

Comment: Yes. It is a spring boot project

Comment: How are your dependencies setup? The DispatcherServlet is part of the spring-webmvc project. Are you pulling in dependencies individually or as part of starter project e.g. org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web

Comment: I am pulling spring-boot-starter-web. Entire project works like a charm. I have some integration tests working in java code with spring boot runner. Also Have a spock and groovy unit tests. Now I am trying to add some "behavioral" groovy tests and this is only when I get this issue.

Comment: Can you share your dependency declarations, or better a Build Scan, just execute the gradle command and add `--scan`?

Comment: scan here (first time using it not sure if this is all) https://scans.gradle.com/s/zzpm2g7rkn2ys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Build Scan](https://scans.gradle.com/s/zzpm2g7rkn2ys) you shared, it looks like you are actually building a webflux project. `@WebMvcTest` only works with `spring-mvc` style webapps. You should be using `@WebFluxTest` instead.